# I have a 10-year UK visa ban; how can I visit my wife?

Tags: visas, uk, spouses, visa-bans

I was banned from entering the UK for 10 years because I didn’t disclose that I was married in my previous application.

I have been married to my wife since 2015 and she is a UK citizen but, when I got married, I was a student and my parents did not approve of me dating someone that is not from Nigeria. So each time I applied, we used a family agent that helps us. I didn’t disclose to the agent that I was married so as not to tell my parents.

Now when I applied to visit my wife in the UK, I was bannned because I didn’t disclose that I was married in my previous applications. I was told the only solution is a spouse visa but I really don’t want to live permanently in the UK so a spouse visa is really not a good option for me.

What other options do I have?

Comment: When there's information you don't want someone to have, the solution is to avoid them seeing the application, not to withhold it.

Comment: I already made the mistake and trust me I don’t have anything to gain by not disclosing that I’m married to a Uk citizen rather I had a lot to gain had I disclosed it but at that time it was complicated and I didn’t even think about it until now that I got the ban.. just looking for solution to my problem at this moment cause it’s all my fault

Comment: Now my wife is in Uk she has been the one visiting me since that’s why I applied for visiting visa to go and see her but got banned cause I didn’t disclosed it in my previous applications when I was a student in uk

Comment: You could meet elsewhere in Europe where you can both get a citizen. Or you could try to get an UK immigration lawyer to look at your case, but that will be rather expensive.

Comment: Did you ever tell UK officials *yourself* that you are not married?

Comment: No I never did but my previous applications u know where they ask if u have relative in Uk I do thick no but that time I didn’t think much about it.. but now it’s been used against me for deception which wasn’t the intention cause there is no reason to lie about my marital statues other than to not let folks to know

Comment: I spoke with Uk immigration lawyer he said the only option is to relocate to Uk and stay with my wife but that’s not an option for me as I have a lot doing in Nigeria just want to be able to visit my wife till she relocate back to Nigeria